# Haproxy 1.8 redirect confusion

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I need some help with my redirects, currently i can the following domains:

http://example.com
http://www.example.com
http://example.net
http://www.example.net

These need to redirect to secure: **https://www.example.com**

But I also have

http://blog.example.com

That needs to redirect to secure: **https://blog.example.com**

I think I'm part way there but I just can decipher how to go from .net to .com

```
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

acl has_www hdr_beg(host) -i www  
acl has_blog hdr_beg(host) -i blog

http-request redirect location https://www.example.com%[req.uri] unless has_www || has_blog
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating this.
Example config:

```
frontend fe_http
    bind :::80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend fe_https
    bind :::443 ssl crt example_net.pem crt example_com.pem

    use_backend bk_example_net if { hdr(Host) -i example.net } || { hdr(Host} -i www.example.net }
    use_backend bk_example_com if { hdr(Host) -i example.com } || { hdr(Host} -i www.example.com }
    use_backend bk_blog if { hdr(Host) -i blog.example.com }
```

Then let the respective web servers handle whether or not the client asked for a hostname with or without the "www" part.

Comment: This is great but i'd really like to handle all redirection in the one place. Also, i forgot to mention that the sites are going to a single backend and each node handles both sites.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but I would argue that web servers are better suited for this than reverse proxies - even though both contain the tools to perform the job. The redirect from HTTP to HTTPS is a bit different because with an HSTS header, this would only happen once every six months or so per client. What you want to do is essentially a rewrite, and that's better done in the web server.